# How to calculate with subquery

Tags: mysql

I am not able to calculate the ratio which

> (ratio = (number of connections to a protocol) / (the total number of
>   connections))

```
select 
     traffic.protocol, 
     ratio
from 
     webserver 
     inner join traffic on webserver.ip = traffic.webserver_ip
where 
     ratio = (select 
                   traffic.*,
                   count(traffic.sourceip) 
              from 
                   webserver 
                   inner join traffic on webserver.ip = traffic.webserver_ip 
              group by 
                   traffic.protocol) /
             (select 
                   count(webserver.ip) 
              from 
                   webserver 
                   inner join traffic on webserver.ip = traffic.webserver_ip) 
              group by 
                   traffic.protocol);
```

Comment: Your SELECT makes no effort to calculate any ratio, and `where ratio = (SELECT *`) is never going to work. Please explain more clearly what you're trying to do, your table schema, sample data, and the desired output from that data.

Comment: I'm guessing that `ratio` is not a column in any of the tables

Answer (score 0):

Try this query and see if it's working.

```
SELECT traffic.protocol, SoIP/WsIP AS "Ratio"
FROM traffic INNER JOIN
(SELECT traffic.*,COUNT(traffic.sourceip) AS "SoIP" FROM traffic GROUP BY traffic.protocol) tA
ON traffic.webserver_ip=tA.webserver_ip INNER JOIN
(SELECT ip,COUNT(webserver.ip) AS "WsIP" FROM webserver GROUP BY ip) tB 
ON traffic.webserver_ip=tB.ip;
```

If you have errors and/or other condition you want to add, please provide a sample data for us to work with.